# interpreting Sensors command line output

Tags: 12.04, cpu, sensors

I need some help in interpreting  the output of sensors command :

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +56.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:        +67.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +38.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +51.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +27.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp7:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp8:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +59.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +59.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +57.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +67.0°C
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The output of `sensors` is usually pretty raw and it really depends on the Kernel support for your particular I²C bus, and how the monitors are attached to the system.

Having said that, the `coretemp-isa-0000` ones are obviously your CPU.

The rest are a bit more of a guess. I would suggest that the first couple could be additional under-CPU thermometers and the others could be various chipset monitors around the motherboard.

It's hard to be exact because it's layered behind ACPI rather than being exposed as a normal I²C device.

Comment: if coretemp-isa-0000 readings are my CPU Temp reading.  how come they are only three readings. I have core i5 processor which has 4 cores .

Comment: `radeon-pci-0100`  <-- likely the graphics card

Comment: Only two of the cores have temp sensors, i'd listen to the Physical Device temp sensor overall (normally each core doesn't have a sensor)

Comment: @Guest does it have 4 cores or does it have 2 physical cores and 2 hyperthreaded virtual cores? My i7 (which has 4 physical and 4 virtual HTs) shows as 4 sensors (one per real core).